# How do I enable CORS in Giraffe?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, f#, asp.net-core-webapi, f#-giraffe

I am unable to successfully perform a Post operation using the Giraffe framework on the server with an Elm client sending the request.

I receive the following message when attempting to test an http request:

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1](https://github.com/bizmonger/Nikeza/blob/master/Server/Nikeza.Server/Routes.fs)
>
> ```
>   Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/register  0
> ```
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request
>
> starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/register  0 dbug:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[1](https://github.com/bizmonger/Nikeza/blob/master/Server/Nikeza.Server/Routes.fs)
>
> ```
>   OPTIONS requests are not supported
> ```

The service implementation is the following:

```
let private registrationHandler = 
    fun(context: HttpContext) -> 
        async {
            let! data = context.BindJson<RegistrationRequest>()
            match register data with
              | Success profile -> return! json profile context
              | Failure         -> return! (setStatusCode 400 >=> json "registration failed") context
        }
```

I then attempted the following and observed the same result:

```
let private registrationHandler = 
    fun(context: HttpContext) -> 
        async {
            return! text "hello world" context
        }
```

**Appendix:**

```
    POST >=> 
        choose [
            route "/register" >=> registrationHandler
        ]
```

The source file can be found [here](https://github.com/bizmonger/Nikeza/blob/master/Server/Nikeza.Server/Routes.fs).

[Elm and CORS](https://github.com/evancz/elm-http/issues/45)

[WebAPI enable Cors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Here's a [Giraffe sample](https://github.com/dustinmoris/Giraffe/commit/ec11a12d5ac69f8d9c911f7b4b42c3188a18e975) that shows the code for supporting Cors.

Comment: Are you performing the request from a different domain to localhost:5000 (for example using the Angular serve command)? It looks like you are dealing with a [CORS preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: My client is also a local host but with a different port number. Shouldn't I be able to test a web app and a separate process service on my local machine?

Answer (score 3):

1. Add package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors
2. In .fs file add:

```ml
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors
```

3. Add UseCors e.g.:

```ml
let configureApp (app : IApplicationBuilder) =
    app.UseGiraffeErrorHandler errorHandler
    app.UseStaticFiles() |> ignore
    app.UseAuthentication() |> ignore
    app.UseCors(Action<_>(fun (b: Infrastructure.CorsPolicyBuilder) -> b.AllowAnyHeader() |> ignore; b.AllowAnyMethod() |> ignore)) |> ignore
    app.UseGiraffe webApp
```

4. In services add cors:

```ml
let configureServices (services : IServiceCollection) =
let sp  = services.BuildServiceProvider()
let env = sp.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>()
let viewsFolderPath = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Views")

services
    .AddCors()
    .AddAuthentication(authScheme)
    .AddCookie(cookieAuth)
    |> ignore
```

Comment: If you run `dotnet new giraffe` it will also auto configure Cors in the default template for you, so you can always create a new app to quickly look up how it is done.